# ionic-native (ionic 2) googleplus login issue on android device

Tags: ionic2, google-plus-signin

I am trying to integrate g+ login in my app. i have followed the below steps:
1. Installed ionic-navtive gplus plugin using: **ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid**

used reversed client id generated from console.developers.google.com. its format is **xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com** .

my app actual bundle id is: **com.mycomp.myappid**

then on click of login button trying g+ native call. here is my ts code:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
GooglePlus.login({}).then((gplusData)=>{
    console.log("gplusData:"+JSON.stringify(gplusData));
  },
  (gplusErr)=>{
    console.log("gplusErr:"+JSON.stringify(gplusErr));

  });
});
```

when trying the above code, its going to error block and printing:
**gplusErr:8**

i dont understand what it means. i also, some other queries:

1. as of now, i have created one iOS, one android app for the respective OS'es. As a cordova app, i should create one only. when i tried with web app, its asking for redirect url and i have given **http://localhost/oauth2callback , http://localhost/**. its giving me 400 error saying **redirect_uri_mismatch** with my appid:/oauth2callback in response text. What can i use there if i can set up a web app for use in my ionic 2 app.
2. what does the above error message means? just 8 is what i am getting in response is what my understanding.

I followed: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-google-login

can somebody help me?